# Checking whether a set system is intersecting

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a set of set systems `g`. I want to select from `g` those sets systems that are intersecting, that is for every two sets in the system, they have at least one element in common. Thus, I tried the code

```
 gIntersecting = Select[g, ForAll[{x , y }, Element[x, #] && Element[y, #],  
  Intersection[x, y] != Empty]]
```

This returned the following two errors

> `Message[ForAll::msgs, {x ∈ #1 && y ∈ #1, x ⋂ y != Empty}, {Intersection::normal}]`

and

> Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in
> `Select[g,\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∀\), \({x, y}, x ∈ #1 && y ∈ #1\)]\(x ⋂ y != Empty\)\)]`

I am still a bit new to Mathematica, so I would love some tips on how to make that work.

The desired outcome is to take a collection of sets, such as g being the sets `g = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}}}`, then the function should return the following `gIntersecting[g] = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}}}`

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please present a minimal example. In your case, include an example for `g` along with a desired outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! A couple basic things happened here: (1) there was a missing `&` after your expression involving slots (`#`'s), and so this was not actually a function (note that bound slots are green and italicized, while unbound ones are pink); it should read `Select[g, ForAll[{x , y }, Element[x, #] && Element[y, #],  Intersection[x, y] != Empty] &]` (2) "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1" means that at position 1 in `Select[...]`, which is `g`, you have an atomic expression (just the symbol `g`) and you shouldn't. If you want to make a function, use `gIntersection[g_] := Select[g, ...]`

Comment: A couple more meaningful things also happened: (3) `Empty` is an internal name with no meaningful content; it is not the empty list (`{}`). (4) `Forall` statements are for variables living in "domains", like `Reals` or `Complexes`, and lists are not domains. (You may notice they are not intrinsically sets either!) `Intersection` works on lists, and *treats* them like sets—but still not like Mathematica "domains". Likewise, `\[Element]` doesn't mean anything with lists, as it's for domains.

Comment: To get what you *do* want depends on whether you have actual lists representing your sets of sets. If so, think about getting the function to evaluate to `True` or `False` for use in `Select`. (Note that `Forall` statements also only evaluate to `True` or `False` after `Resolve` is applied, so they're yet another step away from what's needed.) For this, you could use `AllTrue` twice to iterate through a given set of sets (once for `x` and once for `y`) along with `IntersectingQ` (no need to actually compute the intersection!). This can also be optimized, as this looks at each pair twice!

Comment: I'm starting to think this is long enough to be an answer; I had thought it would be shorter  Your (unoptimized) condition in `Select` could look like `s |-> AllTrue[s, x |-> AllTrue[s, y |-> IntersectingQ[x,y]]]`. This is assuming you're using lists, of course. Hopefully that's enough to get you started, feel free to ask more questions! :)

Comment: `g={{{1,2,3},{1,4,5},{1,6,7}},{{1,2,3},{1,4,5},{8,6,7}}}; allNonEmptyPairwiseIntersectQ[s_]:=And@@Map[Intersection@@#!={}&,Subsets[s,{2}]]; gIntersecting=Select[g,allNonEmptyPairwiseIntersectQ]`